# In 2 Corinthians 5:21, what is the meaning of “sin for us”?

Tags: greek, 2-corinthians, sin

In 2 Cor. 5:21, is there any basis for the translation “sin for us” with the meaning that Jesus was made (incarnated) in “sinful flesh” (flesh subject to temptation, able to be tempted)? He could not literally be made sin, since sin is not an object; it is an idea or an action. Similarly, “the righteousness of God” (later in the verse) is not an object that we could be made into; it is more of a state of being.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Ray, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Answer (score 0):

Flesh by itself is not sinful. It was made good. The instinctive nature we share with animals is a gift that prevents us from having to figure a lot of stuff out.

In the law there are two types of sin, of the flesh, and rebellion. 
In the New Testament, Paul cries out for being both a goat and a sheep. He does not do what he wants to do and does what he doesn't want to do.

The instinct which is a gift is misused when we put ourselves first, or when we decide good and evil by ourselves. If I choose to feed the poor because I think it is a good thing to do, without considering what God says, MY work is like filthy rags because it is MY work. I have usurped God's position s the one who determines good and evil. I have made myself equal to God.

Jesus had a flesh nature, but it was not sinful. He did not wish to die. This is not sinful, if is a gifted instinct. It was put at odds with the scripture which said he had to die.

The question seems more theological than hermeneutical but it is a hermeneutics question only because well-established doctrines cannot be ignored when interpreting individual verses.

He was tempted in every way that we are, but without sin. By this he judged us. He removed our excuses for sin and put us to shame.

He was made to be sin when he took on our sin. Being tempted is not sin or Jesus was not sinless.

It is a Greek logical error to presume an idea like "sin is not an object" and make judgements on scripture rather than to accept scripture and wrestle to understand the esoteric meanings of it. Love is not an object, is the Word one? Only because the Word is Christ. Is Truth an obect? He is the Truth.

> 2Co 5:21 For he hath made him [to be] sin for us, who knew no sin;
>   that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.

The point where he was made to be sin is the point that he became sin incarnate. This is similar to him being Love incarnate, or the Word incarnate.

The symbol of the serpent lifted up in the wilderness is a symbol of Christ on the cross.